# How to keep historical values of a data point in SSAS

Tags: ssas

we currently have a report that displays a data point value change week to week.  This is stored in a data warehouse with a 'snapshot' field showing the date pull of those values.  This date can also be mapped to a 'snapshot' dimension for other snapshot related information (flags on what kind of pull it was, whether it's the current pull or the previous pull etcetera)

In regard to cube development (ssas) is this a common practice or is there a mechanism for handling this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Typically the snapshot data is stored in its own periodic snapshot fact table (see Kimball methodology).  Then in the SSAS database, the fact table is brought in as a measure group (just like the other fact tables).  The only difference is going to be the aggregation function specified for the measures...typically facts in a snapshot fact table are not fully additive so you can't use SUM() as the aggregation function.  The easiest way to think about it is in terms of a bank account balance...you can't add the balance across all the months to get the balance at the end of the year.